# warehouse RM notification configuration for every 10% of credit used

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

how can I set warehouse RM notification for every 10% of credit used in snowflake. I have checked the settings which are already there but I did not found specific settings to configure alert notification which can give notifications on every 10% of total credit.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only get five notification triggers, so you'd probably want to set at 20% increments like this:

```
use role ACCOUNTADMIN;
      
CREATE RESOURCE MONITOR "MY_RESOURCE_MONITOR" WITH CREDIT_QUOTA = 1000 
 TRIGGERS 
 ON 20 PERCENT DO NOTIFY 
 ON 40 PERCENT DO NOTIFY 
 ON 60 PERCENT DO NOTIFY
 ON 80 PERCENT DO NOTIFY
 ON 100 PERCENT DO NOTIFY
;
ALTER WAREHOUSE "TEST" SET RESOURCE_MONITOR = "MY_RESOURCE_MONITOR"; 

use role SYSADMIN;
```

Comment: looks helpful, **thanks** for answering the question.